# Defining Set Using Set Comprehenension

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Define the following sets by comprehension:
1. The set of all positive integers.
2. The set of all even natural numbers.
3. The set of all square roots of 144.

I am Using the set Notation for its answer:
That is:
{ x | x is a number and x is greater than zero }

Is it right?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. It appears your question is attracting downvotes because you have not included the progress you've made. If you add that, then I'm sure you will get a much more enthusiastic and warm welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: All of these should be of the form $$\{x\in\text{[some known set]}:\text{[some necessary and sufficient conditions on }x]\}.$$

For example, if I wanted to describe the set of digits ($0$ through $9$) by Comprehension, I might say $$\{x\in\Bbb Z:-1<x<10\}.$$